# Laravel where clause is not working after multiple orWhere clauses?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am querying vehicles with model name and type but these where clauses are not at the end after adding`orWhere`. When I comment or remove these `orWhere` Clauses then its work.

```
$models = Vehicle::join('vmodels', 'vmodels.vehicle_id', '=', 'vehicles.id')
    ->join('vehicletypes', 'vehicletypes.id', '=', 'vehicles.vehicletype_id')
    ->join('brands', 'brands.id', '=', 'vehicles.make')
    ->join('companies', 'brands.id', '=', 'companies.name')
    ->select('vehicles.slug as vslug', 'brands.name as brandname', 'vehicles.id as vid', 'vmodels.*', 'vehicletypes.name as vtype', 'companies.status as cstatus')
    ->where('brands.name', 'LIKE', "%{$term}%")
    ->orWhere('vmodels.name', 'LIKE', "%{$term}%")
    ->orWhere('vmodels.year', 'LIKE', "%{$term}%")
    ->orWhere('vehicletypes.name', 'LIKE', "%{$term}%")
    ->orWhere('vehicles.model', 'LIKE', "%{$term}%")
    ->where('companies.status', '=', 1 )
    ->where('vmodels.status', '=', 1)
    ->where('vehicles.status', '=', 1)
    ->paginate(30);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Group your `orWhere`'s like,

```
$models = Vehicle::join('vmodels', 'vmodels.vehicle_id', '=', 'vehicles.id')
    ->join('vehicletypes', 'vehicletypes.id', '=', 'vehicles.vehicletype_id')
    ->join('brands', 'brands.id', '=', 'vehicles.make')
    ->join('companies', 'brands.id', '=', 'companies.name')
    ->select('vehicles.slug as vslug', 'brands.name as brandname', 'vehicles.id as vid', 'vmodels.*', 'vehicletypes.name as vtype', 'companies.status as cstatus')
    ->where(function($query) use($term){
        $query->where('brands.name', 'LIKE', "%{$term}%")
            ->orWhere('vmodels.name', 'LIKE', "%{$term}%")
            ->orWhere('vmodels.year', 'LIKE', "%{$term}%")
            ->orWhere('vehicletypes.name', 'LIKE', "%{$term}%")
            ->orWhere('vehicles.model', 'LIKE', "%{$term}%");
    })
    ->where('companies.status', '=', 1 )
    ->where('vmodels.status', '=', 1)
    ->where('vehicles.status', '=', 1)
    ->paginate(30);
```

Reference : https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#parameter-grouping

Answer (score 1):

if you want to simulate AND/OR statement for your SQL queries with Laravel query builder, you should do it like this:

```
((A or B) and (C or D)) or (E)

ModelName::join(...)->join(...)
           ->where(function($query){
               $query->where( A )
               ->orWhere( B )
           })
           ->where(function($query){
               $query->where( C )
               ->orWhere( D )
           })->orWhere( E )
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this one:

```
  $models = Vehicle::join('vmodels', 'vmodels.vehicle_id', '=', 'vehicles.id')
    ->join('vehicletypes', 'vehicletypes.id', '=', 'vehicles.vehicletype_id')
    ->join('brands', 'brands.id', '=', 'vehicles.make')
    ->join('companies', 'brands.id', '=', 'companies.name')
    ->select('vehicles.slug as vslug', 'brands.name as brandname', 'vehicles.id as vid', 'vmodels.*', 'vehicletypes.name as vtype', 'companies.status as cstatus')
    ->where('brands.name', 'LIKE', "%{$term}%")
    ->where('companies.status', '=', 1 )
    ->where('vmodels.status', '=', 1)
    ->where('vehicles.status', '=', 1)
    ->orWhere(function($query) use ($term){
      $query->where('vmodels.name', 'LIKE', "%{$term}%")
             ->where('vmodels.year', 'LIKE', "%{$term}%")
             ->where('vehicletypes.name', 'LIKE', "%{$term}%")
              ->where('vehicles.model', 'LIKE', "%{$term}%")
    })   
    ->paginate(30);
```